# Duplicate error messages in .NET Core - error CS0116

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-code, .net-core, dotnet-cli

Steps to reproduce

```
dotnet new console
(introduce a bug in Program.cs)
dotnet restore
dotnet build
```

The typical output would be:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.548.43366 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Program.cs(5,5): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [/Users/xxx/Documents/myproj/myproj.csproj]

Build FAILED.

Program.cs(5,5): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [/Users/xxx/Documents/myproj/myproj.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.77
```

You can see the error CS0116 is reported twice.

Is there a way to avoid the duplication in the reporting of errors?

Comment: Weird... I notice the same behaviour. It looks like it's a sort of a summary since it's displayed after the **Build FAILED** message. May I ask if and why this is a problem for you?

Comment: @EmielKoning, it bugs me when I have 500 warnings from stylecop

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second error is part of the console logger's summary. This can be disabled by passing in `/clp:NoSummary` to msbuild. However, there is currently a bug in the CLI when it is the first MSBuild argument to `dotnet build`. Add any other MSBuild command before it to make it work. Since you want to reduce the verbosity, let's just use `/nologo` for the workaround:

```
dotnet build -c Release /nologo /clp:NoSummary
```

However, it works great if you use MSBuild directly:

```
dotnet msbuild /clp:NoSummary /p:Configuration=Release
```

In the upcoming 2.0.0 release, the CLI always overrides the summary parameter for `dotnet build`, so you'll have to use `dotnet msbuild` instead (I opened an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/7009) on that).

Comment: Works exactly as described. Thanks.

Comment: Works with latest 2.1.4 release without needing to use dotnet msbuild

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own MSBuild logger, instead of using the default console logger. There are really good instructions in *[Build loggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/build-loggers)*.

Essentially, you could make your own logger that captured all the data, and then emitted a simple summary at the end.

`dotnet build /noconsolelogger /logger:YourCustomLogger.dll`

Comment: This solution is overkill. I was looking for an answer like the accepted one.